# Передача изображения между приложением и сервером

Tags: java, android, база-данных, spring, изображения

Есть клиентское андроид приложение и серверное, в основе которого лежит Фреймворк *Spring*.

Нужно организовать хранение и передачу изображений с клиента на сервер. Какие есть хорошие практики для этого?

Сейчас реализовано как `кодирование в base64 строку -> передача -> раскодирование`.

Является ли это оптмальным способом передачи? И в чем плюсы и минусы хранения изображений на сервере в виде файла / и в базе.

Comment: `Является ли это оптмальным способом передачи?` вы про кодирование массива байтов картинки в base64 и передачи его по сети с раскодированием? Нет. Лучше просто передавать массив байт. Покажите в вопросе как вы передаете и принимаете картинку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше картинку сразу передавать массивом байт через Multipart. "base64" - увеличивает объём трафика, + за зря тратите время процессора на конвертацию. По поводу хранения на сервере, то изображения лучше хранить в файлах. Во первых можно будет сразу давать готовый линк на изображение и не дёргать БД. А во вторых представьте сколько будет занимать места копии Вашей БД, скажем через год ...